# Enable and disable the system searching option

Tags: c#

how to enable/disable the system searching option thru c# program

yes i want enable/disable (Start->Search) option. already i have disable it thru program i don't know how to enable it..

Comment: Are you talking about Windows Search (Start->Search)? If so, why?

Comment: You should probably clarify which 'system searching' you are referring too. Are you talking about the Windows Indexing service? Do you want to stop the service, or stop it from indexing a particular directory? Why are you trying to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should instanciate a ServiceController and stop/start it

```
ServiceController myService = new ServiceController("WSearch");
...
myService.Stop(); 
... 
myService.Start();
```